# CSS block with background image not including space after header

Tags: css

I'm trying to create [this box](http://atlas.czg.net/atlas/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Screen-Shot-2012-12-17-at-3.05.22-PM.png), but it's a little over my head. I can't get the spacing after the white header text to display correctly.

The live version is [here](http://atlas.czg.net/), and the current CSS is below. A standard < p > inside the div ignores the bottom padding on hblock and I can't help but think I'm going about this the wrong way. Is there a simpler way to create this element or something I'm missing in the code?

Many thanks.

```
#lheaderblock{display:block;
padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
background-image:url('http://atlas.czg.net/atlas/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/caption_header_blue.gif');
height:160px;
width:90%;
border:1px solid #000000;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;}

hblock{position:absolute;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:14pt;
padding:10px 0px 20px 15px;}
```

Comment: remove the absolute positioning from the hblock.  Then you just need to tweak your padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `<hblock>` is. When browsers don't know either, they will render them as inline element. You need to give it `display: block` and remove `position: absolute`. Tweak the padding and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it had to be simple. Learn something new every day.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use an appropriate header tag like h1 or h2 instead. You need to accept this as an answer if it answered your question.